# Redirect all WordPress posts and pages to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, hook-wordpress

I want to redirect all the old posts and pages on a WordPress site to the home page as I'm shutting the site down but want to show people a thank you for your support page no matter what page they go on.

I have tried several `.htaccess` pieces of code but with no success, so any working code samples out there?

Answer (score 6):

If you have direct access to the files, you'd be able to write yourself a solution:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_homepage' );

function redirect_to_homepage() {
    $homepage_id = get_option('page_on_front');
    if ( ! is_page( $homepage_id ) ) {                                                                                  
         wp_redirect( home_url( 'index.php?page_id=' . $homepage_id ) ); 
    }    
}
```

I used [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76802/redirect-entire-website-to-a-single-page).

Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

Below code will redirect all page/post to home page.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'wh_redirect_to_home');

function wh_redirect_to_home()
{
    if (!is_home() || is_page() || is_single())
    {
        wp_redirect(esc_url(home_url('/')));
        exit();
    }
}
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Believe you need to revisit the conditional logic here as this results in an infinite redirect loop.